# How can I get the adjusted values with respect to a specific effect in a linear mixed effects model?

Tags: lme4-nlme

I'm using `R` and `lme4` to estimate the parameters of a model

```
model = lmer(response ~ fixed_effect + nuisance_effect + (1 | random_effect), data = data, REML = FALSE)
```

where `fixed_effect` is the categorical factor of interest, `nuisance_effect` is a numerical factor, and `random_effect` is a categorical factor.

I want to visualize the data while accounting only for the `nuisance_effect`, so I want to get the residuals with respect to that effect only. Using `residuals(model)` gives me the residuals for the entire model.

So, my question is twofold:

1. Is this the right approach to visualization here?
2. How can I pull out the residuals in this way?